# Linq Query for TOP 11-20

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, sql-order-by

I am Getting an error while executing this query :

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to
>   Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method
>   'Skip'.

```
var data = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
               where xx.USER_ID == userid
               orderby xx.ID
               select xx.TEMPLATE_ID).Distinct().Skip(10).Take(10));
```

Actually, I am already using `OrderBy` in that query.But, I'm getting the error.

Comment: My guess is you need an `OrderBy(...)` between `Distinct()` and `Skip()`

Comment: @DonatasK. It's right there in the question: `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.`

Comment: The reason the existing `orderby` is ineffective is that `Distinct` destroys the ordering. The existing `orderby` should be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying `OrderBy` before `Skip`, like this:

```
var data = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
            where xx.USER_ID == userid
            select xx.TEMPLATE_ID).Distinct()
                                  .OrderBy(x => x)
                                  .Skip(10).Take(10));
```

Comment: Because of the projection (`select xx.TEMPLATE_ID`), the first query returns a set of ints. I guess you can't then order it by `.ID`.

Answer (score 4):

It tells you exactly what is wrong and what to do about it:

```
var data = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
                                where xx.USER_ID == userid
                                orderby xx.ID
                                select xx.TEMPLATE_ID)
           .Distinct()
           .OrderBy(x => x)
           .Skip(10)
           .Take(10));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  data = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
                            where xx.USER_ID == userid
                            orderby xx.ID
                            select xx.TEMPLATE_ID).Distinct().Skip(10).Take(10);

  data1=data.ToList(); // it will fetch only 11-20.
```

Comment: -1 because that is semantically very different. It will fetch *all* items from the database into memory.

Comment: That will pull back everything from the DB and then do the `LIMIT` in memory, rather than at the database. This query could blow up on a very large table.

Comment: Your update will throw exactly the same exception as the one the OP is already facing.